# Module bundler for TypeScript in GreaseMonkey

Tags: javascript, software-development, programming, compiler

I am writing a GreaseMonkey plugin in TypeScript. I am compiling
`main.ts` file into `main.js`, and then put it on GreaseMonkey. The
output file format looks like vanilla JavaScript, and GreaseMonkey
consumes it happily. Now the project grows larger, I plan to split the
code into several files. However, I failed to find a build system that
works.

Requirements:

- It should bundle everything into a single JavaScript file.
  GreaseMonkey only takes one file.
- It should generate vanilla JavaScript. I don't think things like
  `System.import` works in GreaseMonkey.

#### Possible behavior

Given

```
// lib.ts
export function greet(name: string) {
    console.log(`Hello, ${ name }!`);
}
```

and

```
// main.ts
import { greet } from './lib.ts';

greet("Tom");
```

it returns

```
// main.js
let lib_public = {};
lib_public.greet = function greet(name: string) {
    console.log(`Hello, ${ name }!`);
}
lib_public.greet("Tom");
```

Answer (score 7):

Webpack is all you need! OK, some plugins here and there(webpack, webpack-cli, typescript for obvious reasons, ts-loader for webpack-Typescript interaction/compilation), but here is the recipe, assuming your code is in `src` folder (`Main.ts` being the entry point) and you want your `lib.user.js` in `dist` folder:

**webpack.config.js**

```
// required for path resolution for dist folder
const path = require("path");
// used to access the BannerPlugin
const webpack = require("webpack");
// required for pretty format for the Userscript banner
const stripIndent = require("common-tags").stripIndent;

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/Main.ts",
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    mode: "development",
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".js"]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: "lib.user.js"
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.BannerPlugin({
            raw: true,
            banner: stripIndent`
                // ==UserScript==
                // @name    Your lib name
                // @namespace   https://path.com/your/lib/namespace
                // @version 1.0.0
                // @author  Your Name
                // @description Your lib description
                // @include https://www.example.com/*
                // @copyright   2019, Your Org
                // ==/UserScript==`
        })
    ]
};
```

Important bits from **package.json**:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "common-tags": "^1.8.0",
    "ts-loader": "^5.3.3",
    "typescript": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack": "^4.29.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.3"
  }
```

**Build:** `npm run build`, which will invoke `webpack`, as instructed in the `scripts` section of `package.json`.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is [rollup](https://rollupjs.org/). It allows compiling into one file (using iife)